# Dialogflow - MediaResponse working in Simulator but not Google Assistant - Server Requirements

Tags: networking, dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google, digital-ocean

I am creating a little Dialogflow-Chatbot that is supposed to be used in Google Assistant. Gist of it is that it's supposed to send .mp3-Files (>120s) that are on my private server as MediaResponse to certain commands.

For that, I have set up my server as Fulfillment for these commands, which is supposed to send a MediaResponse. For now, the Backend is written in Python and sending pure JSON-Files. I am using the example from https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#df_json_media_response:

```
SAMPLE_PAYLOAD_JSON = {
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "Ok, here is a file for you."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mediaResponse": {
                            "mediaType": "AUDIO",
                            "mediaObjects": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Name-of-my-file",
                                    "contentUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3",
                                    "description": "3 min meditation",
                                    "largeImage": {
                                        "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg",
                                        "accessibilityText": "Album cover of an ocean view"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": [
                    {
                        "title": "That was appropriate"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "I didn't like this one"
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this precise Media Response works perfectly well, both in the simulator at https://console.actions.google.com, as well as in Google Assistant on my phone.

However, like I mentioned I want it to work with files on my server, and for some reason if I change the contentURL to a URL on my server (I simply used the original sample-file, copied to my server: https://cstenkamp.de/meditation_files/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3), it doesn't work anymore in Google Assistant. It still works fine in the simulator, but if I try it on any phone using Google Assistant, it tries to load the audiofile and ends with "Unable to play audio".

So I am left wondering, if there are any server requirements for Google Asstant Media Responses specifically, that are not there for the simulator.

About my server: It is the smallest DigitalOcean Droplet, 512MB Ram, Ubuntu 16, with apache2. HTTPS is accessible, and the file can be accessed from a browser (see second link). Pinging it takes 25ms in contrast to 15ms for storage.googleapis.com. The URL comes from NameCheap, if that is somehow relevant :shrug:

Thanks already, if I didn't specify anthing well enough please let me know.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "private server", you mean the one at cstenkamp.de with HTTPS, correct? And the certificate there *isn't* self-signed?

Comment: Yes, I mean the one at cstenkamp.de with HTTPS. The certificate is from letsencrypt.

Comment: If you try to access the URL directly via your phone (ie - not using the Assistant), does it play?

Comment: yip, it does play directly on my phone.

Comment: Does it have to do with CORS headers?

Comment: If it did, what could I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had API problem (usually timeout from requests) when use Dialogflow from Python script in Digital Ocean machine, and fix that when I add 8.8.8.8 Google DNS as a primary server, it's starts work.